# How to use Views Page + Attachment to show parent and children nodes?

Tags: views

I have a site with a node type `Lesson`, which has a `Category` field that points to a taxonomy term.

There is another node type `Exercise` which is a child to a `Lesson` node.

I previously figured out how to make one view page for a term url that displays both a parent and child nodes. But I was thinking that maybe it is better to have a page view with an attachment, where the page would display a `Lesson` node's fields and an attachment would display the children `Exercise` node's fields.

The page view has relationship set to taxonomy term and contextual filter set to the category. Then it is set to display `Lesson` fields.

In the attachment view, parent is set to page, relationship is set to a `Lesson` reference field. But I have no idea what to choose as contextual filter because there is no filter for me to choose that will get me the lesson id. The attachment doesn't seem to have a way to get the parent node id (lesson id) from a contextual filter, since the url will only have the term id.

Any ideas on how to make the attachment display the children of the parent that is displayed in the page view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're getting stuck messing with relationships in the view - this shouldn't be needed to do what you're trying to do.  You can accomplish this with these basic settings:

**Lesson**: All your lesson fields + term reference to category

**Exercise**: All your exercise fields + term reference to category

Your view's page display just needs to be set up to display `content` of type `lesson`.

The part that I think you're missing is setting the contextual filter.

1. Add the contextual filter `Content: Has taxonomy term ID`
2. Provide default value -> `Taxonomy Term ID from URL`

Your attachment should be set to show the `exercise` content type.  Add the same contextual filter to this display and make sure you have `inherit contextual filters` checked.

This will give you a page that displays the lesson, followed by all exercises tagged with the matching category.

Comment: But the thing is, the exercises are attached to a given lesson. I think what you are suggesting would display the exercises that are in the same category as a lesson, but not necessarily in the lesson, you know what I mean? For instance, I have a category `scales`, and a lesson `Major Scales` and exercises in that lesson, but there is also a lesson `Non-Major Scales`, also in category `Scales`, but with different exercises. So exercises in both lessons are in category `Scales`, but the exercises are attached to specific lessons.

Comment: The same method applies to this situation - just add a "lesson" taxonomy reference to both content types and use that in your views instead of category.

Comment: Do you mean lesson entity reference? The only term reference is to category. Right now an exercise has a lesson reference, but a lesson does not have a lesson reference since that would just be the lesson node id.

Comment: You can use entity reference instead if that's what you prefer.  Add a contextual filter for NID on both views.  On the page view, provide a default value of Content ID from URL.  On the attachment, add a relationship to your entity reference (the first one).  Change the contextual filter to hide view when no argument is present.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does the filter get the node id from the url if the url only has the term id? Thanks for the patience!

Comment: Because the unaliased path is /node/xxx, xxx being the ID, unless you are saying that your content is a taxonomy term page instead - not sure why that would be the case though

Comment: Yes, it is a taxonomy page. There is a menu with the categories (Scales, Pick Technique, etc) and when someone clicks a category (taxonomy page) I want them to see a listing of Lessons in the category and the exercises under the lessons.

Comment: You can still use the method 4 comments above, you just use taxonomy term ID contextual filter instead of NID

Comment: That approach does not group the exercises with the lessons properly. I really do think that to get this to work I would have to save the lesson id in the page view as a global and then read it in the attachment and then override the query...